# Sending data from a raspberry pi to a java application?

Tags: java, windows, raspberry-pi

I need to send data from raspberry pi to a windows pc and vice versa. Because I created one java applet in windows. The java program should access the data of the raspberry pi. Can anyone tell me how can the java program access the data of the raspberry pi?

Comment: Hi! It can be done in multiple ways. You must be more specific, in your question. What did you try so far?

Comment: I have created one Local server (XAMP) in windows. Can raspberry pi update the values of the database which is present in Xamp server in windows?

Comment: Is it possible by connecting LAN cable?

Comment: If it is not possible can you share one of your best ideas to share data between raspberry pi and windows??

Comment: Well an easy way would be to create a webservice in xamp and use curl or a program to call the webservice.

Comment: could u please tell me how to use curl ?

Comment: The most efficient way for you to check it is to see it's documentation. But you will have to combine it also with some form of shell scripting. If you choose to follow this path.

Comment: In any case the best way to let people help you is to upload your attempts to solve the issue. And ask about specific problems you faces.  Then people can try to help.

Comment: Your question is far too vague and broad. Are the Raspi and PC connected? By wired Ethernet? By WiFi? By RS232 serial cable? By Bluetooth? How far apart are they? How often do you need to send data? How much data? 4 bytes or 8MB? Is the dataflow only one way or bidirectional?

Answer (score 0):

**Hello**, if the *Raspberry* is on the same network as the other computer, you could establish a [socket connection](https://www.javatpoint.com/socket-programming) between the *PI* and the *PC* and send *files*, *packets*, *etc.* to the pc.

Have fun, I hope I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

I created an example Java-application which can share data between PC, Raspberry Pi and Arduino using Mosquitto. This is a great way to share data. For more information see code in https://github.com/FDelporte/JavaOnRaspberryPi/tree/master/Chapter_11_Queues and a short description on my blog https://webtechie.be/post/2019-10-27-controlling-arduino-with-mosquitto-and-javafx-on-raspberry-pi/